# usort table by date given by XML

Tags: php, arrays, xml, html-table, usort

My problem is, that I change my date from valuable

```
$date
```

into an array, which is called

```
$sortDate
```

Now, I want to take the array, and sort it by date. My function for sorting looks like this.

```
   function sortArray($data, $field) {
        if (!is_array($field))
            $field = array($field);
        usort($data, function($a, $b) use($field) {
            $retval = 0;
            foreach ($field as $fieldname) {
                if ($retval == 0)
                    $retval = strnatcmp($a[$fieldname], $b[$fieldname]);
            }
            return $retval;
        });
        return array_reverse($data);
    }
```

now, here is definition of valuables I have spoke about in the begining.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://www.hokejbal.cz/xml/2017-2018/shedules/227.xml');

    foreach ($xml->SKUPINA as $skupina) {
        if ($skupina['id_sku'] != 1613)
            continue;
        foreach ($skupina->UTKANI as $utkani) {
            $away = $utkani->AWAY;
            $date = new DateTime($utkani->DATUM);
            $sortDate = array();
            $sortDate[] = $utkani->DATUM;
            print_r($sortDate); //this is just control line, yes, it is array.
```

Now, I want to sort the date...so I write this

```
        foreach ($utkani->DATUM as $item) {
                $sortDate[] = array(
                    'datum' => $item->DATUM
                );
            }
            if (isset($sortDate)) {
                $sortDate = sortArray($sortDate, array('datum'));
```

so, now I am in point, when the elements should be sorted by the $date in my eyes, so I am ready to write something like this

```
<tr>    
<td nowrap><?=$sortDate->format ('m.d.y') ; ?></td>
</tr>
```

but in this point, I get only error call...

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function format() on array in C:\xampp\htdocs\SKKelti2008\Tabulky_rozpisy_statistiky\A\page-rozpis-1718.php:62 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in
>    C:\xampp\htdocs\SKKelti2008\Tabulky_rozpisy_statistiky\A\page-rozpis-1718.php on line 62

*As a finish, this is just my full code, so you can get idea about what is going on with the table. It isn't important for solving of the problem, but it can help.*

```
    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
            <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">
<div class="svazTabulky">
<TABLE>
    <TR>
        <th colspan="9">1. Národní hokejbalová liga 2017/2018</th>
    </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD nowrap>DATUM</TD>
    <TD nowrap>ČAS</TD>
    <TD nowrap>MÍSTO</TD>
    <TD nowrap>DOMÁCÍ</TD>
    <TD nowrap>HOSTÉ</TD>
    <TD nowrap>Výsledek</TD>

  </tr>        
        <?php
             function sortArray($data, $field) {
            if (!is_array($field))
                $field = array($field);
            usort($data, function($a, $b) use($field) {
                $retval = 0;
                foreach ($field as $fieldname) {
                    if ($retval == 0)
                        $retval = strnatcmp($a[$fieldname], $b[$fieldname]);
                }
                return $retval;
            });
            return array_reverse($data);
        }

        // put your code here

    $xml = simplexml_load_file('http://www.hokejbal.cz/xml/2017-2018/shedules/227.xml');

        foreach ($xml->SKUPINA as $skupina) {
            if ($skupina['id_sku'] != 1613)
                continue;
            foreach ($skupina->UTKANI as $utkani) {
                $away = $utkani->AWAY;
                $date = new DateTime($utkani->DATUM);
                $sortDate = array();


                 foreach ($utkani->DATUM as $item) {
                    $sortDate[] = array(
                        'datum' => $item->DATUM
                    );
                }
                if (isset($sortDate)) {
                    $sortDate = sortArray($sortDate, array('datum'));
                    print_r($sortDate);

                    foreach ($utkani->HOME as $home) {
               if ($home['kod_cmshb']!=3202007 and $away['kod_cmshb']!=3202007)               continue; 

            ?>
              <tr <?php if($utkani['kod_cmshb']==3202007){ ?> class="beroun" <?php } ?>>
                <td nowrap><?=$sortDate->format ('m.d.y') ; ?></td>
                <td nowrap><?=$utkani->CAS ?></td>
                <td nowrap><?=$utkani->MISTO ?></td>
                <td nowrap><?=$utkani->HOME ?></td>
                <td nowrap><?=$utkani->AWAY ?></td>
                <td nowrap><?=$utkani->GH ?>:<?=$utkani->GA ?></td>
              </tr>        
            <?php
                } 
        }
        }

        break;
    }

?>
</TABLE>
    <p>Data převzata z <a href="http://hokejbal.cz"> hokejbal.cz</a></p> 
</div>
            </div><!-- #content .site-content -->
        </div><!-- #primary .content-area -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
}

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run:

`var_dump($sortDate);`

that will result in:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["datum"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#7 (0) {
    }
  }
}
```

In that case `$sortDate->format ('m.d.y')` will not work because you want to run the [format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) method on an array.

You declare a `$date` variable, but you do not use it in this code.

`$date = new DateTime($utkani->DATUM);`

Perhaps you were looking for `$date->format ('m.d.y') ;`?

Comment: Well, I use $sortDate because i can not use function sortArray on $date, because $date is not array –